# Close and Then Open iOS Application to Specific ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I've been looking on SO for the answer to this question but none seemed to work. My question is : when I close and then re-open an application in Swift, how do I make it so that it goes to a specific ViewController(i.e, to a PIN login page)? I know it has to do with App Delegate but all other suggestions ends in a crash. Below is my App Delete:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle:Bundle.main)
    let secondViewController: PINViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PINViewController") as! PINViewController
    window?.inputViewController?.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
}
```

Comment: So you need to open always a specific view controller whenever app opens after terminated?

Comment: you have to find current visible controller then open it

Comment: @Himanth yes, for example, when the app is closed and opened again, I would like to go to a controller that makes the user put in their "PIN" number to continue(similar to the Credit Karma app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func presentToVC(yourVC:UIViewController){
        let navEditorViewController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: yourVC)
        navEditorViewController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        navEditorViewController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
        (self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController).visibleViewController?.present(navEditorViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: @rengineer don't mention it.   please check answer status. may be helpfull for someone . Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle:Bundle.main)

    let initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PINViewController") as! PINViewController

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here created extension to find out current visiblecontroller

```
extension UIViewController {
    func topMostViewController() -> UIViewController {
        if self.presentedViewController == nil {
            return self
        }
        if let navigation = self.presentedViewController as? UINavigationController {
            return navigation.visibleViewController.topMostViewController()
        }
        if let tab = self.presentedViewController as? UITabBarController {
            if let selectedTab = tab.selectedViewController {
                return selectedTab.topMostViewController()
            }
            return tab.topMostViewController()
        }
        return self.presentedViewController!.topMostViewController()
    }
}

extension UIApplication {
    func topMostViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        return self.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.topMostViewController()
    }
}
```

after that you can use it whenever you want

```
let topMostViewController = UIApplication.shared.topMostViewController()

 let secondViewController: PINViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PINViewController") as! PINViewController
    topMostViewController.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put the presentation related code in **applicationWillEnterForeground** method, this will be invoked when next time user clicks on the appIcon and launch the app.

Here is the code to make it working.

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle:Bundle.main)
    let secondViewController: PINViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PINViewController") as! PINViewController
    window?.rootViewController?.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are moving the app from background to foreground state, you can try this:

```
  func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

       // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
       let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle:Bundle.main)
       let pinViewConroller: PINViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PINViewController") as! PINViewController
       self.window?.rootViewController.present(pinViewConroller, animated: false, completion: nil)

    }
```